# how to get javascript data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have requirement to show the local calendar date (not locale).

This javascript can return the date string. Can I show that date string in flutter mobile using this javascript.

```
<a lang='my-en' id='mcalr' href='https://yan9a.github.io/mmcal/'>Myanmar Calendar</a>
<script src='https://yan9a.github.io/mmcal/mcalrs.js'></script>
```

Result string is below

Sasana Year 2565  , Myanmar Year 1383  , Thadingyut new moon, Wednesday , Sabbath.

Do I need to use webview or is there any other plugin there?

Comment: try [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)

Comment: I have tried it but it is not showing calendar date. It is just showing Myanmar Calendar. Scripting is not triging.
Html(
      data: """<div class=CalS>
        <a lang='my-en' id='mcalr' href='https://yan9a.github.io/mmcal/'>Myanmar Calendar</a>
        <script src='https://yan9a.github.io/mmcal/mcalrs.js'></script>
      </div>""",
    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think flutter_html does not support javascript. I use flutter_js and create the js file in assest.